# Back up Mac using CarbonCopyCloner with command line only?

Tags: backup, command-line, rsync, single-user, carbon-copy-cloner

**Background:**

I never expected to have *only* command line access to my Mac, but the day has arrived!  :)  Due to a video card problem, any attempt to boot the normal OS or recovery partition results in a kernel panic.  However, I *can* boot into Single User mode!  (The screen has a bunch of green horizontal lines through it every other pixel, but it is still readable.)

I have checked and verified that my data is intact.  I have a Genius Bar appointment to get the video card replaced.

I have a couple of backup drives on which I have CarbonCopyCloner backups of my computer, however these are out of date.

---

**I want to back up my Mac from the Single User Mode command line using CarbonCopyCloner** before I take it for the video card replacement.

(I found [this link on the `ccc` tool](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/using-ccc-command-line-tool-start-stop-and-monitor-ccc-backup-tasks), but I don't have ccc 4.)

Questions are:

1. How can I use CarbonCopyCloner 3.5.7 from the Single User Mode command line to update one of my full backups before I take the machine in for service?
2. *If* this can't be done from the command line with this version of CCC, how else could I back up all data before taking it in for service (from Single User mode)?

Comment: Your best bet is to connect the broken mac to another mac in target disk mode then do the backup from the other mac.

Comment: @fd0, yes, but I don't have another Mac.  Is rsync the best bet, then?

Comment: @fd0 I ended up going to my mom’s and using her Mac to boot mine in target disk mode and back it up using CCC 4.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Boot to Single User Mode with one (empty) backup drive attached. Execute the indicated standard commands:

- `/sbin/fsck -fy`
- `/sbin/mount -uw /`
- Get the disk identifier of the external backup drive:

  ```
  gpt -r show disk1 #(or disk2, disk3) search for the proper drive with gpt because *diskutil* won't work in SU mode
  ```
- Mount the external drive's main partition (e.g. disk1s2) to /Volumes/externaldrive and create a new folder:

  ```
  mkdir /Volumes/externaldrive
  /sbin/mount -o nosuid -w -t hfs /dev/disk1s2 /Volumes/externaldrive
  mkdir /Volumes/externaldrive/new_backupdir
  ```
- Backup your main drive with rsync e.g:

  ```
  rsync -aE --exclude='/Volumes' / /Volumes/externaldrive/new_backupdir
  ```

  If you want to backup only the folder /Users modify the rsync command accordingly. Please check `man rsync` for the appropriate options. Some of the useful options (like -v) don't work in SU mode - at least for me. Depending on your system, the options set and the excluded items the rsync command will yield some minor errors.

---

This backup isn't bootable per se. You may create a bootable backup though by backing up to the root of the external drive and blessing the appropriate boot.efi.

Comment: Is `rsync` available on stock OS X?

Comment: @MaxRied Sure. But some options don't work in SU mode!

Comment: Do you know if it is used by OS X internally?

Comment: @MaxRied I don't know of any use of it...

Answer (score -1):

If you are OK with not using CCC to make the backup you could use the command line to create a regular disk image.  Not sure if this is something that will work for you, but I don't have any knowledge as far as CCC goes.

`sudo hdiutil create ~/Desktop/{disk image name}.dmg -srcdevice /dev/{disk identifier}`

Comment: Hmmm, this looks like it would create on the *main* hard disk, a backup of some *different* hard disk.

Comment: As I understand it CCC uses rsync under the hood.  Although I don't have the exact command you would need, this likely is possible